# SQL - Select Top result for each player in the last 10 results of each player

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a SQL request from my table play :

```
user_id   playDate      score   game_id
1   27/02/2018 16:21    77244   119
1   27/02/2018 16:20    218364  119
1   27/02/2018 16:08    272240  119      <--- This one
1   27/02/2018 16:08    118055  119
1   27/02/2018 16:08    173677  119
1   27/02/2018 16:08    112328  119
1   27/02/2018 16:08    169296  119
1   27/02/2018 16:08    56090   119
1   27/02/2018 16:08    51172   119
1   27/02/2018 16:08    95293   119
1   27/02/2018 16:08    109572  119
1   27/02/2018 16:07    20421   119
1   27/02/2018 16:07    458186  119      <--- NOT This one because not in 10 last play
1   27/02/2018 16:07    196987  119
1   27/02/2018 16:07    75904   119
1   27/02/2018 16:07    117530  119
2   01/03/2018 10:54    223446  119
2   01/03/2018 10:52    617292  119
2   01/03/2018 10:51    177332  119
2   01/03/2018 10:48    41071   119
2   01/03/2018 10:47    103833  119
2   01/03/2018 10:46    327581  119
2   01/03/2018 10:41    737348  119
2   01/03/2018 10:36    8476    119
2   01/03/2018 10:36    252481  119
2   28/02/2018 18:21    205360  119
2   28/02/2018 18:19    63601   119
2   28/02/2018 18:19    242404  119
2   28/02/2018 18:13    18503   119
2   28/02/2018 18:03    167226  119
2   06/01/2018 14:21    386115  119      <--- This one
2   06/01/2018 11:25    216266  119
2   06/01/2018 11:25    149841  119
5   28/02/2018 16:13    402902  119      <--- This one
5   28/02/2018 12:11    156313  119
5   28/02/2018 11:45    192914  119
5   28/02/2018 11:44    117458  119
```

**My objective is to get :**

MAX(score) for each user_id
looking only in user_id LAST 10 play (via Order BY playDate DESC)
For only 1 game_Id

The expected results with these data would be :

```
user_id Best score
  5      402902
  2      386115
  1      272240
```

I tried GROUP_CONCAT, LIMIT etc but can't find a working solution..
Many thanks !
Olivia

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
SELECT user_id, max(score) as maxscore
FROM table_name
WHERE game_id = 119
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY playDate DESC LIMIT = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, but any advice/comment would be appreciated !

```
SELECT
  play.user_id AS id,
  fos_user.username AS username,
  MAX(play.score) AS score
FROM
  play INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      user_id,
      GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY playDate DESC) grouped_score
    FROM
      play
    WHERE game_id = :game
    GROUP BY user_id) group_max
  ON play.user_id = group_max.user_id
     AND FIND_IN_SET(score, grouped_score) BETWEEN 1 AND :limit
JOIN fos_user ON play.user_id = fos_user.id 
GROUP BY 
    play.user_id
ORDER BY
    play.score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select user_id, max(score) from play where game_id = 119 GROUP BY user_id order by playDate desc limit 10;
```

Comment: no.. this limit all results to10, but I need 10 results for each player